# Can not call .js in html(using knockout)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am new to knockout using knockout2.1.0.
I have an external java script file, but it is not called in my html file. I can not understand.

I have added the following in my html file

```
  <script src="Scripts/TestJavascript.js"></script>
```

**JS File**

```
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js">
///<reference path="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js">
$(function AppViewModel() {
this.firstName = ko.observable("rash");
this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
this.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
})
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

thanks.

Comment: i don't mean to come across as harsh, but you question is very confusing.. could you provide some more relevant code perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't creating a ViewModel. You are passing it to jquery.

Try

```
var AppViewModel = function() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable("rash");
  this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
  this.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
      return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  }, this);
})
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

this code must appear either after the bound html, or within a document ready event (jquery)

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("rash");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```